# opencv splitting mask into peripheral and central area

Tags: image-processing, opencv, contour

After getting a contour from an image, i want to split the area inside it into a peripheral and a central parts. The split has to be made according to a fixed percentage threshold among the peripheral and the overall area.
I thought of a solution is to calculate the minEnclosingCircle and then misure the ratio between the distance of the point from the center of countour and the radius of the circle.
Any other ideas?

Comment: what about pointPolygontest? http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygon#pointpolygontest.

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is eroding and dilating

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html

Erode or dilate and subtract the result from the original. From that you can calculate the percentage threshold.

EDIT:
Just saw the pointPolygonTest http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygon#pointpolygontest

Seems to be the better approach.